# Chart control in C#

Tags: c#

Chart doesn't display and no any error.
Can Any one suggest me why my chart is not plot and whats wrong going on here.

```
Chart1.Titles.Add("Case");
Chart1.DataSource = dt;
Series s = new Series();
s.XValueMember = Convert.ToString(x);
s.YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(y);
Chart1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sounds like Chart1.Series hasn't been initialised.

Comment: It would seem that you haven't added any series to your chart. Can you show us more code, particularly where you create the chart object and add the series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: You seem to be changing questions here - in your original post you said you got an index out of range error - now you say you get no error. If this is a new problem then you should create a new question, not modify the original.

Answer (score 0):

what you're missing here is adding your newly creates series to chart series collection.

```
Chart1.Titles.Add("Case");
Chart1.DataSource = dt;
Series s = new Series();
s.XValueMember = Convert.ToString(x);
s.YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(y);
//one line that you're missing
Chart1.Series.Add(s);
Chart1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should set chart properties.

**Step 1:** Go to Chart properties then click on Series.

[image]

**Step 2 :** Change the name of Series. Here, I set the name to Case. We can also change the ChartType

[image]

Change your code as follows :

```
    chart1.DataSource = ds;  
    //set the member of the chart data source used to data bind to the X-values of the series  
    chart1.Series["Case"].XValueMember = Convert.ToString(x);  
    //set the member columns of the chart data source used to data bind to the X-values of the series  
    chart1.Series["Case"].YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(y);  
    chart1.Titles.Add("Case");
```

Comment: @Mehul_Lad I hope this is use full.